# Is there an elegant way to pass 'do nothing' as a lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a method, `foo`, which requires a lambda parameter. The lambda is invoked by `foo` with arguments. I don't actually want anything to happen upon execution of the lambda.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
foo(->(*) {})
```

This looks a tad ugly, and I have to believe that there is a more elegant and legible way of writing this built into the Ruby language.

Is there a better way of passing a 'do nothing' lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend rethinking `foo` instead.

That being said I do not think there is a more elegant way, but if you really wanted to you could add something like this (which is uglier in my opinion than what you have)

```
module Kernel
  def noop
    Proc.new {}
  end
end
```

Then call as

```
def foo(blk)
  blk.call(1,2,3,4,5)
end

foo(noop) 
#=> nil
```